# Polymer property observer does not trigger when keys have periods?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

My Polymer module has a property that is an object called `pokemonToType` that maps a pokemon (string) to its type (string):

The module's ready function asynchronously adds values to the mapping.

```
Polymer({
  is: "pokedex",
  properties: {
    pokemonToType: {
      type: Object,
      value: {},
    },
  },
  ready() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.set('pokemonToType.bulbasaur', 'grass');
      this.set('pokemonToType.charmander', 'fire');
      this.set('pokemonToType.mr.mime', 'psychic');
    }, 4242);
  },
  observers: [
    "pokemonToTypeChanged(pokemonToType.*)",
  ],
  pokemonToTypeChanged(changeRecord) {
    console.log(changeRecord);
  },
});
```

Unfortunately, `this.set('pokemonToType.mr.mime', 'psychic');` fails to trigger the observer, mostly likely because the key contains a period. How could we solve this issue (trigger the observer) without removing the period from the key string (of `mr.mime`)?

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3127

Comment: making use of computed properties rather than assigning them with a time out is best in my mind.